# Thread synchronisation: Wait on two bool variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I want to wait for two `bool` variables to be true in one thread. They are changed in different places. I can use boost in my project, but not C++11.
I did find Info on how to use mutexes and condition variables, but im not sure if its possible to wait for two mutexes.
This is some pseudocode of my program.

```
bool job1_dataready, job2_dataready;

//t1:
void job1()
{
   //do stuff
   job1_dataready = true;
}

//t2:
void job2()
{
   //do stuff
   job2_dataready= true;
}

main()
{
 boost::thread t1(job1);
 boost::thread t1(job2);

 if(job1_dataready&& job2_dataready)
 {
    //do stuff with data from both jobs
 }

}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Your booleans aren't protected by a mutex or other synchronization mechanism, nor are they atomic. That means access from the main and worker thread would be unsynchronized and thus Undefined Behavior. (This isn't an answer to your problem, just to point out that your current attempt isn't going anywhere.)

Answer (score 6):

from what I see, you don't need bool variables, use [std::thread::join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) instead:

```
main() {
    std::thread t1(job1);
    std::thread t1(job2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    // do jobs after threads t1 and t2 finish working
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer with one minor problem - OP states that C++11 is not used, but boost is. For the answer to be stellar, consider expressing the same thing with boost.

Comment: Perfect solution for my problem. I am using `boost::thread` of cource

Answer (score 1):

you would block on the condition variable, check your boolean values when woken, and either go back to waiting or continue processing. Your threads will signal the condition variable after they have set the boolean flag. All with appropriate mutex locking of course. You can wait on an infinite number of conditions, just check when woken after blocking on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In simple situations like this, you wait on two mutexes simply by locking them in order. First you lock the mutex from thread 1, then the mutex from thread 2. If thread 2 would finish before thread 1, the main thread would simply not block when locking mutex 2.

However, note that this is an answer you your question, but not a solution to your problem. The reason is that you have a race condition with the mutex: the main thread might lock the mutex before the worker thread even starts. So, while Andrei R.s response (`std::thread::join`) isn't a direct answer, it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to set your two `bool`s just before the respective threads terminate, then [Andrei R.'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36474820/3233921) of just `join`ing the two threads is definitely the best way to go.  However, if your threads actually continue working after the `dataready` points are reached, and are thus not terminating yet, you need a different approach.  In that case, you could use two [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)/[`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) objects, which would look something like this:

```
std::promise<bool> job1_dataready, job2_dataready;

//t1:
void job1()
{
  //do stuff
  job1_dataready.set_value(true); // The value doesn't actually matter
  //do more stuff
}

//t2:
void job2()
{
  //do stuff
  job2_dataready.set_value(true);
  //do more stuff
}

main()
{
  std::future<bool> job1_future = job1_dataready.get_future();
  std::future<bool> job2_future = job2_dataready.get_future();

  boost::thread t1(job1);
  boost::thread t2(job2);

  job1_future.wait();
  job2_future.wait();
  if (job1_future.get() && job2_future.get()) // True unless something was aborted
  {
    //do stuff with data from both jobs
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising. Unfortunately, I cant use c++11, and the boost::future seems not to exist in my boost version (1.49, can't update).

Comment: Hm, according to the docs for 1.49.0 there should be [`boost::unique_future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures).